# is their any date filter in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

1) 
   i have a leave request form in my HRM application, i want that when a user enter the "from_date", the "to_date" should be greater than "from_that"?

2)
   In my app i have a leave model in which user can defined leave type and day's allowed.In my second model leave_request user can request for leave according to leave type.Everything is working well.Now i want to display leave balance available to user on basis of allowed day's in leave_request form?

Migration leave.rb:

```
  class CreateLeaves < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :leaves do |t|
          t.integer :user_id
          t.integer :company_id
          t.string  :leave_type
          t.integer :allowed_leaves
          t.text :description, :limit => 500

          t.timestamps
        end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :leaves
      end
    end
```

And leave_request.rb:

```
 class CreateLeaveRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :leave_requests do |t|
          t.integer :employee_id
          t.integer :leave_type
          t.date :from_date
          t.date :to_date
          t.text :reason_for_leave
          t.string :contact_during_leave, :limit => 10

          t.integer :user_id
          t.integer :company_id

          t.timestamps
        end
      end

      def self.down
        drop_table :leave_requests
      end
    end
```

And can i validate number of leaves available like if user do not have enough leave balance than their should be a message like"You do not have enough leave to request " etc.

Comment: You'll get better results if you post one question at a time.

Comment: Ok Jordan i will take care of it, thanks for guidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi friends here i came with a new answer of my second question

i used following line of code to fix my problem:

```
<label><a href="/leave_types">Leave Type</a></label>
  <label>Balance</label>

 <% for leave in @leave_types %> 
   <%= leave.leave_type %>
   <%= leave.allowed_leaves%>
 <% end %>
```

This displayed all my leave_types in my new leave_request form.

Comment: Now i m to calculate leave balance through j query on leave_request form,please some buddy help me

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is not very comprehensible. What is "`from_that`"? If you're asking how to check if one date is before or after another, it's easy: `Date` and `DateTime` include `Comparable` so you can compare any two just like you would two numbers, e.g.:

```
>> DateTime.now > 1.day.ago
# => true

>> DateTime.now > Date.tomorrow
# => false
```

Comment: Oops.. please make it more clear ,where should i implement it , in my model or in view directly, because i have used jquery date picker instead of "date_select"

Comment: Hi, I created a validation for "from_date" and "to_date" and it is working

Answer (score 1):

> You can write your own validator, something like this (untested code):

```
class LeaveRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :has_enough_leave

    def has_enough_leave
       if( to_date - from_date > employee.allowed_leave.days )
           errors.add(:to_date, "You do not have enough leave to requestt")
       end
    end

    ...
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, this is giving a type error:expected numeric or date

Answer (score 0):

I have done  my first problem in following way:

```
class LeaveRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :leave

    validate :from_date_and_to_date

         def from_date_and_to_date
           if(to_date != from_date)
             errors.add(:to_date, " should be greater than from date" )
           end 
         end
```

Comment: But this is work only for today's date ,is their any way to be able to work on future date